# Refresh Map on HTML page when data change

Tags: carto, refresh

I am new about Carto and I have a question.
I would a HTML page with Carto Maps (using JavaScript) and I would refresh the page when the data on CartoDB change.

So I ask if there is a sort of Push Notification (as CometD library).

Comment: Just to be clear do you want to refresh the page? Or do you want to update what is on the map? or update elements in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

There is no push notificiations in CARTO but you can use [SQL API](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/sql-api) to check if your data has changed and then refresh the layer from your frontend code. This is actually a very common pattern.

In order to know if your data has changed you need to implement your own logic using maybe a trigger and a sort of `updated_at` column or associated metadata table.

Disclaimer: I'm a solutions engineer at CARTO